# How cold can it get outdoors before air source heat pump sees damage from running?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heat-pump, winterizing

I'll start with some background to set the scene for my question.  About 15 years ago I got a heat pump and natural gas furnace to replace the air conditioner and natural gas furnace that had broken beyond repair.  The thinking was that a heat pump would save me on natural gas costs during the mild cold of spring and fall with the natural gas furnace keeping me warm through the harsh cold of winter.  Since then the fancy thermostat controlling the system died and natural gas got cheaper.

The thermostat had the ability to select which heat source was used based on outdoor temperature, with a user selected point for switching, a feature that appears to be quite rare on thermostats available today and certainly not on the low end of the price range.  I believe my old thermostat was set to run the heat pump for heating if outdoor temperatures were above 40F, and run the furnace otherwise, if not 40F then certainly something about that set point.  The heat pump also provided cooling like the air conditioner it replaced, and as readers of this likely know an air source heat pump is pretty much a common air conditioner with a bit of different circuitry.

The thermostat died months ago and I've had trouble finding some kind of one-for-one replacement at a price I'd be willing to pay.  The point of the heat pump was to save money and with natural gas prices being so low the margins are thin on what I'm willing to pay in replacement parts.  I bought a thermostat that is able to run my furnace and the heat pump in cooling only mode, but with the threat of rising natural gas prices recently, or natural gas simply being unavailable for a while, it has come to mind again the option of restoring the heating function of the heat pump.  There's also the potential of another furnace failure and having to force the heat pump to make up for that, certainly only temporarily, if at all possible.

In doing some research on this there's recommendations on not running my heat pump in below freezing temperatures as at that point it would be cheaper to run the furnace.  That assumes current pricing and availability of natural gas.  Other recommendations are to run the heat pump until the outdoor temperatures get to something like -20F as at that point the COP of the heat pump gets below 1.0 and resistance heat becomes cheaper to run.  This assumes I have resistance heat and that I much care if the COP is above 1.0.  At some point the heat pump will have a COP below that and I'm putting 5000 watts of electricity in to get 4000 watts of heat out, and I'd be quite pleased about that as the alternative is seeing my house get frozen.

I give that rather lengthy introduction as to avoid the usual answers I've found in my research so far.  I don't care if the heat pump gets expensive to run because it is too cold outside.  I care only about preventing damage in a situation where the furnace is unavailable.  There is a point at which the R-134a and/or lubricant will freeze solid in the compressor and by running it I'd tear it to pieces.  At one atmosphere R-134a will freeze solid at something like temperature of dry ice, but the system is not at one atmosphere.  That's a good place to start in answering my question about damage to the heat pump, at what temperature will the R-134a freeze solid at pressures seen inside the piping?

There's other ways the heat pump could be damaged.  The outdoor temperature could be so cold that the R-134a doesn't vaporize like it should and the pump sees "liquid slugging" or simply "slugging".  I've seen cases on slugging causing a heat pump to merely run roughly in cold weather, or to a point the liquid slugs running through the pipes damage valves or something and it no longer provides any heat.

I've seen temperatures as low as -60F in winter where I live before, that's rare but it can happen again.  Based on the operating manual my heat pump is capable of running far below the 30F or 40F the installers set for the switch to furnace for heat.  At some point there's a risk of damage from operating at low temperatures as opposed to mere presence within those temperatures, we know heat pumps can survive very low temperatures if not running since we will see bone chilling winters and the heat pumps run fine once the outdoor temperature rises again.  Knowing this will guide what safety mechanisms I put in place for my repairs, will provide guidance in case of some kind of emergency, and should be of interest to others as heat pumps become more popular.  I plan to do any work myself but if things get too complicated then I'd still need some guidance on what to tell the HVAC professionals what work I want done.

I have a degree in electrical engineering so I know enough physics, chemistry, and thermodynamics to separate most of the brilliance from the BS.  In looking for answers the reports I've seen of cold weather damaging heat pumps there was no mention of what the specific temperature was (merely something like "unusually cold night") or the temperature reported didn't "smell right" and the failure may have been merely coincidental to the weather event, or if not coincidental then the "last straw" on an already failing heat pump.

Comment: How about the make/model of your heat pump? While the concept applies to any heat pump, the specifics will vary widely, and without knowing the specific make/model it is impossible to guess the (a) safe temperature and/or (b) cost-effective temperature.

Comment: I think heat pumps have a low temperature where they do not supply heat, depending on the heat pump.  I do not think cold temps themselves do the damage, maybe to your pocketbook paying the electricity.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  The heat pump is a common model from Goodman, fairly new at the time with a 14 SEER rating.  It appears a 14 SEER rating isn't as impressive as it was then but it should give an idea on the operation.  I don't want people to get too caught up on the specific model since the failure modes should be fairly universal.  Also, I don't care about the cost effective temperature as that will vary over time as the relative prices for electricity and natural gas change.  I can look up the COP at different temperatures and figure out the cost effective point myself.

Comment: 14 SEER says nothing about how cold the unit can work. "common model from Goodman" also says nothing. Model # is the key.

Comment: @crip659  There is certainly a point at which the heat pump will not supply heat.  In fact it appears there's a point in which the heat pump will actively cool the house if run.  I just want to look at the point of damage to the heat pump and how to protect from that.  Any matters of calculating cost of operations I can do myself based on pricing of electricity and natural gas at the time.  Also, if the furnace fails the cost of natural gas becomes quite irrelevant, only the point of damage.  I'd be willing to push the boundaries of damage based on my level of desperation at that time.

Comment: Evidently you have this information, since you say: "*Based on the operating manual my heat pump is capable of running far below*" so **What, exactly, does the Fine Manual Say about that??** That is surely your best source of information for your particular system. Mine heat effectively to -15°F, but that has nothing to do with yours... As for backup heat, resistance heating is dirt cheap to buy, which is why slumlords love it. Expensive to run is not their problem.

Comment: "What, exactly, does the Fine Manual Say about that??"  It says nothing.  It gives COP charts to a point in which it gets below 1.0 but at no point does it say, "beyond here there be dragons."  It's been a while since I looked at the manual, and it has become lost, so I'm  going from memory to give you an immediate answer.  I'll look again when I find it but I thought this could be a healthy discussion not just for myself but also for others.  I'm looking for an answer on where no heat pump made by human hands could operate, not just for my specific model should I need a replacement soon.

Comment: No heat pump made by human hands? That gets down to within microKelvins of absolute zero, from what I recall the low temperature physics folks down the hall doing 30 years ago. Apparently 38 picoKelvins was achieved in 2021.

Comment: "No heat pump made by human hands?"  I'm being a bit facetious with that comment, lighten up.  The point is that common residential heat pumps have their limits, and it will be based on very real world failure modes such as the lubricant freezing into asphalt.  (Again I'm being a bit facetious about asphalt, lighten up if that bothers you.)  The specific failure point will vary some with the design but the designs on common residential heat pumps don't vary so much that there would be an order of magnitude difference.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement, it's about a healthy discussion.

Comment: @JACK  The question is about a failed thermostat and I'm attempting a DIY repair.  To perform this DIY repair while preventing damage to the heat pump I'm seeking some information from other homeowners that have air source heat pumps on what they've seen as failure modes of their heat pumps, and at what temperatures they occurred.  There's a theoretical aspect to this, such as in why this failure happens, but the larger point is still a DIY repair on a common-as-rocks heat pump.  I'm not asking which parts to buy, only some general dea on what kind of parts to look for.

Comment: Yes, it's about a failed thermostat and you found some  but don't want to pay the price. I just see this going on and on without a definite answer.

Comment: @JACK  Yes, and now that there's a high probability on natural gas prices increasing I've reconsidered the price I'm willing to pay for a new thermostat.  That means I'm looking again for a thermostat, or whatever, and I'd like to know the experience from other DIY HVAC people what they know about heat pumps so I don't repeat their mistakes and break something that would be very expensive to replace.  My heat pump has no low temperature protections built-in, so one way to answer my question is what low temperature protections have others seen and at what temperature do they trip.

Comment: I voted to close because "needs clarity". Specifically, need the model # of OP's heat pump. Without such details this is an interesting discussion but not an answerable question.

Comment: If someone absolutely, positively, must have the model number then it can be worked out from the description I gave.  Goodman will use a series of code numbers to specify SEER, refrigerant, heat pump or air conditioner, power (in tons, watts, or BTU/hr), and perhaps a couple other options.  I didn't specify the model because I can't find it at the moment, and because it appears to be largely irrelevant since Goodman uses the same manual for a whole series of product model numbers.  Just knowing it is a Goodman R-134a heat pump from 15 years ago should be enough to find the specs.

Comment: This is a very similar question I just found from years ago that was not closed for lack of "clarity" in spite of not specifying the specific model of heat pump.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/102439/heat-pump-minimum-compressor-temprature  How is my lack of "clarity" different?

Comment: For one thing, that question asked *primarily* about efficiency. You are asking primarily about *damage*. Those are (as you have already stated) two different questions. In addition, I was not even on this site at the time. If I had been, I might very well have asked "What model?"

Comment: Best guess on model series is SSZ14 from Goodman.  This indicates R-410a refrigerant, not R-134a (which is apparently more common in automotive use of that era then residential) as specified earlier.  I didn't find the specific model yet, it's on the small size of this series so assume 3 tons or smaller and running on single phase 240VAC @60Hz.  Close enough?

Comment: I checked with Goodman and they will not provide technical support to homeowners, only licensed installers, so that's a dead end.  What must I do to re-open this question?  I could open a new question just like it but I'd like to preserve what's been added here so far instead.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you've tried to find the freezing point of R134a at various pressures and you were stymied. That's because the freezing point of almost all pure liquids (except water) barely changes with pressure until the pressure is enormous.

You've studied chemistry and physics, so you've seen phase diagrams. This is for CO2, and R134a will be similar in shape with a different temperature scale. Note that as soon as the temperature is high enough for liquid to appear, the freezing point -- the boundary between solid and liquid -- remains a nearly constant temperature until the pressure is in the hundreds of atmospheres.

[image: e]

(Credit: Ben Finney, Mark Jacobs - Wikimedia Commons)

So with a freezing point of about -142F, lower than the lowest temperature ever recorded on earth, your refrigerant can not and will not ever freeze.

If your existing heat pump can be damaged by low temperature, it won't be due to the refrigerant freezing.

Comment: Much better answer than mine; addresses the question directly from first principles.

Comment: "I assume that you've tried to find the freezing point of R134a at various pressures and you were stymied."  Indeed I was.  I bring that up because I know propane is (or was) a common refrigerant and it can freeze solid at temperatures people could reasonably see during a cold winter night on Earth.  Propane is a gas at atmospheric temperature and pressure, generally stored as a liquid in pressurized steel bottles, and in the right (or very wrong) conditions could freeze solid in some piping.  This can happen with other common refrigerants as well.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the heat pump. Many modern units are operabable, and deliver useful heat, down to temperatures well below freezing. (Mine claims to be good down to 5 degrees Fahrenheit.) Obviously their efficiency suffers when they can't scavenge as much energy from the surroundings, but that's safely within their design envelope.

The more interesting question is where the trade-off point would be at which they have lost enough energy to make it worth switching back to fossil-fuel heat. I vaguely remember being told the efficiency crossover point for mine vs. my high-efficiency gas hydronic system was somewhere around 25F. (That may not be the cost crossover, of course, depending on relative prices of fuel and electricity at the moment.) Some systems offer an optional (extra cost) controller which ties into the fossil-fuel furnace's thermostat circuits to make that cut-over happen automatically; I don't have such a controller but a friend does.

Comment: "The more interesting question is where the trade-off point would be at which they have lost enough energy to make it worth switching back to fossil-fuel heat."  As the question lays out the assumption is the furnace is not available for some reason.  The concern of long term costs is now gone, only on if the house can remain safe to occupy by running the heat pump instead or if it is time to get in the 4x4 and face the storm.  I know many heat pumps will have safety mechanisms built in to prevent running at too low of temperature but mine has none, that is the responsibility of the installer.

Comment: Granted, that's a digression. But my answer stands: Check the specs of your unit, but if it was made recently it can probably survive running at quite low temperatures and deliver at least some heat at temperatures within its rated operating range. Whether that's enough heat to keep the building habitable depends on the specs of the system and the characteristics of the building. The latter have been addressed in other answers, but the only way to determine it for your structure is to measure your structure.

Comment: "Some systems offer an optional (extra cost) controller which ties into the fossil-fuel furnace's thermostat circuits to make that cut-over happen automatically"  For my system that automatic cut-over was done by the thermostat, and that thermostat died.  In doing repairs I'd want two cut-over points in the system somehow, one for cost savings and another for protection from damage.  All research so far has lead to cost savings, so I have all kinds of advice on that, and ambiguous answers on the point of damage.  I'm concerned about preventing damage with my question.

Comment: "But my answer stands: Check the specs of your unit"  All research done so far only answers the question on optimizing for costs, but I don't care about that.  I only wish to prevent damage.  I realize there will be some variation based on the model but there's some answer based on physics and common manufacturing practices to give at least a ballpark on the point of damage.

Comment: @MacGuffin -- your low temperature limit will be in your heat pump's specification sheet -- if you can't find it yourself, get us the make & model number of the outdoor unit and we can give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about backup heat for the gas being out, and you have documentation of the point where your COP is less than 1.0, just install resistive heaters for backup use below that point. They are dirt cheap to buy, (even cheaper or free to get used) just expensive to run when you need them, but they are a COP of 1.0 and very simple and reliable.

*If* you have power to run them at all.

As for the question of "How cold must it be to damage the unit?" that will be specific to a particular unit, and if not documented, will require a technical support call to the manufacturer.

Comment: Getting resistance backup heat is an excellent suggestion but... There is nothing I could buy that would be as powerful of heating source as the heat pump with the efficiency cut-over bypassed.  That is nothing except a resistance heat furnace. I did some looking at that and there's no room in my duct work for that so it would be a very expensive option.  Also, even if this were something I'd consider the question still applies as there could be a need for such an emergency bypass if there's a significant delay in getting the backup heat installed.  With storm damage recently that is possible.

Comment: But wait, there's more...  If I were to scatter 120VAC heaters about the house then I may still want the heat pump running as added heat and to spread that heat out to prevent pipes freezing and such.  Something like a wood fireplace is also an option but if I could prove to myself that the heat pump is an option for backup then I could breath easier without the added expense.  I thought someone might have some idea on what point residential heat pumps in general fail from experience, either as a homeowner or HVAC installer.

Comment: A big reason a lot of people don't have heat pumps is because the 1970s heat pumps generally did not work well, if at all, below freezing, making them moderately OK in Florida and nearly useless in New York. The technology has changed. But even though the "average" is far better now (or 15 years ago as is your situation) than 40 years ago, there is (and certainly was 15 years ago) a wide range of capabilities in terms of efficiency, low temperature operations, reliability, etc. Getting "in general" information about 15-year-old heat pumps is about as useful as getting "in general" info.

Comment: about 15-year-old cars. A 15-year-old Prius has very different characteristics from a 15-year-old F150. Which one is "better"? Depends on your needs. Which one will do better in winter? in summer? Which one will haul more stuff? Which one is most cost-effective to run? Etc. Same with heat pumps or a lot of other things. But if you give us a specific model # and related specifications then *maybe* we can actually figure this out.

Comment: This is not like comparing a Prius to a F150.  This is like comparing a Ford 1/2 ton 4x4 F150 to other trucks made in the last 40 years. They all use steel engine blocks, lead-acid batteries, motor oil, water and glycol coolant, rubber tires, and so much more in common.  Now, if I were to leave such trucks out in the cold what is the lowest temperature I could expect them to startup and move under their own power?  Maybe the F150 does a bit better than the Dodge but the temperature at which both fail is going to be within some reasonable margin of error.  My heat pump question is no different.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  If you believe that a 15 year old heat pump using R-134a is somehow distantly inferior to a model made in the last year using whatever refrigerant might have replaced R-134a since then it would be useful to make a comparison on how much they differ and why.

Comment: And the starting point is to **TELL US THE MODEL # OF THE UNIT YOU CURRENTLY HAVE**.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  The specific model doesn't matter.  Just pick one of the approximate same specs because they all perform nearly identically.  If you believe otherwise then I'd like to know why.  I don't know the specific model and by all indications that is not relevant.  Perhaps things improved since with new models but it appears that is more on the efficiency (SEER/HSPF) than anything fundamental impacting how or when they fail at low temperatures.